# plot.ly Bar plot axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, plotly

I am trying to plot a Bar plot of a pandas df column.

```
df[z1z2].head()

MN-SW_TO_MN-SE    562
IA-2_TO_MN-SE     345
MN-SW_TO_MN-WC    259
MN-SW_TO_MN-SW    184
ND_TO_MN-NW       163
Name: z1z2, dtype: int64
In [126]:


data = [Bar(y=df['z1z2'].value_counts()[0:50])]
iplot(data)
```

Note: that `df['z1z2'].iplot(kind=Bar.....)` does fails with credential errors. I guess you can't call `iplot` directly from `pandas` offline?

[image: Bar plot]

In any case, now how do I plot the x-axis, which are categories i.e. MN-SW_TO_MN-SE etc.

I am working offline within Jupyter notebook.

If someone can also point me to documentation that shows examples of what else is possible for Bar plots or any other plot I would be grateful.

Yes, I do know where the full reference documentation is for plot.ly. However, it is not intuitive and not easy to use for anyone that isn't a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your categorical x-values directly to Plotly. In the example below the first column contains the categories (`x=df.iloc[:,0]`).

```
import string
import pandas as pd
import plotly

plotly.plotly.sign_in('username', 'api_key')

data = [[c, i] for i, c in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

plotly.plotly.plot([plotly.graph_objs.Bar(x=df.iloc[:,0], y=df.iloc[:,1])])
```

[image: Output from snippet]

What else is possible with Plotly's bar charts? The best way for me was to look at existing examples and try to reverse engineer them. The documentation is fairly complete but cryptic without examples.